# Android: get position of imageView inside a general framelayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

In my app I have this situation in the layout:

I have a general FrameLayout and inside it I have four LinearLayout; inside each LinearLayout I have inside two small LinearLayout;
now my question is, can I detect the exact position of of these last Linear but considering the general FrameLayout...so in this way I can position a new frame exactly in the same position where is these Linear...
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
View generalFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.generalFrameLayout)
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
while (view.getParent() != generalFrameLayout) {
    x += view.getX();
    y += view.getY();
    view = view.getParent();
}
x += view.getX();
y += view.getY();
```